# How to deal with unknown classes with a neural network classifier?

Tags: classification, neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

I have a small RNN with a softmax output, which succesfully classifies sequences within a known set of n classes.

Now I have the problem that there might be sequences in the test data which do not belong to any of said classes. The model has just been trained with known classes.

Of course, my model will try to lump in those unkown sequences into one of the given n categories, creating wrong results with fairly high propability.

How to deal with unkown/untrained sequences that do not fit into any of the given/trained categories? What kind of measures could I take to mark these unknown sequences as unkown and therefore not part of said n classes.

Comment: Good question. This is not my area of expertise, but sometimes in machine learning classification, people classify into target class vs. not (rather than A vs B), & I gather people sometimes do this & build up when there are many classes. If you tried the latter, is it possible a sequence could be classified as 'not' for all target classes?

Comment: @gung thank you for your suggestion. I'll try this out and come to you later.

Answer (score 1):

If examples of sequences which don't belong to any of your classes already appear in your training data, a possible option is add an $n+1$th class called something like 'other' and label such sequences as belonging to this dummy class. Your Network will then (hopefully) learn to detect such examples.

If, however, these sequences only appear at test time, then as you say it is correct that your network will have no way of detecting them and there's unfortunately no way around that.

Comment: Yes, I should have clarified: The sequences of unkown classes only appear in the test data. I was wondering, whether it would be possible to add an additional class to the ouput which would classify any sequences that don't fit the other ones.

Comment: In that case, your original NN will be hopelessly lost, unfortunately.
What you could do, however, is build an additional model that aims to detect if an incoming sequence is a sample from the same distribution as your training data or if its something entirely different. This is called (unsupervised) Anomaly Detection and there's several methods that try to deal with it - which one might be appropriate depends on the details of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Thresolding Softmax*  is one of the way to identify the unknown classes in test data set.(i.e) If o/p of softmax is less than a threshold we declare it unknown class thereby reducing the False positives. However the  drawback is choosing the right threshold.

Other way around to handle the unknown classes present only in test dataset is described in this paper [Reducing Network Agnostophobia](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.04110v2.pdf) by
Akshay Raj Dhamija, Manuel Gunther, and Terrance E. Boult

Answer (score -1):

Contrastive learning plus thresholding

Comment: This is being automatically flagged as low quality, 
probably because it is so short.
At present it is more of a comment than an answer by our 
standards. Can you expand on it? We can also turn it into 
a comment.